# Scraping webpage with PhantomJS after button event

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am new to javascript and I am trying to capture an html file mostly generated by javascript code.

The site I want to scrape is this link:

http://www.modcloth.com/shop/dresses/luck-be-a-lady-dress-in-black-and-red

For this specific webpage, I would like to capture all the output after clicking the button named `viewall`.

The code below is able to capture the current display of the webpage, but it does not seem to capture the display after clicking the `viewall` button. I have been banging my head against this problem for a couple of days now, and was hoping someone might have a better idea.

```
// scrape_techstars.js

var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'modcloth.html'

page.open('http://www.modcloth.com/shop/dresses/luck-be-a-lady-dress-in-black-and-red', function() {
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
      $("#viewall").click();
    });
    var content = page.content;
    fs.write(path,content,'w')
    phantom.exit()
  });
});
```

Comment: The other question doesn't incorporate the button interaction, which I think might be causing me issues.

Comment: Have you tried to surround `var content = page.content;
    fs.write(path,content,'w')
    phantom.exit()` with `setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 5000);`?

Comment: @Artjom B. ... you are a lifesaver. Thank you so much.

Comment: That's basically what the highest-voted answer in the linked duplicate says, but the 3rd and 4th answers are more elaborate.